# libxml2 in leopard unfound?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, libxml2

I read somewhere that libxml2 is available in XCode4. However, I'm getting a lot of errors running Product > Profile. The current `Header Search Paths` for Adhoc and Debug is set to: `/usr/include/libxml2`

But when I browse through this physical path in Snow Leopard, there is no libxml2 there. Here is a sample error:

```
*:No such file or directory
Libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory.

'*' undeclared here (not in a function)
'XML_ELEMENT_NODE' undeclared here (not in a function)

'*' undeclared here (not in a function)
'XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE' undeclared here (not in a function)
```

Comment: What version of XCode are u using?That might be the problem. And for iphone atleast it's not built in you have to add the framework yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the build settings for your iPhone App project and set

- `Other linker flags = -lxml2`
- **and** `Header Search Paths: $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` **or** `Header Search Paths:/usr/include/libxml2`

When developping under XCode, GCC uses the `-isysroot` option that relocates the root of the SDK. If you add `/usr/include/libxml2` in the header search paths, it will be translated at compilation time to the `usr/include/libxml2` folder INSIDE the current SDK.

Comment: Thanks, only a comment, in Mountain Lion  Header Search Paths:/usr/include/libxml2 seems not work anymore.